# How to make Chakra's <Text> component inline?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I can't figure our how to make the Chakra  component inline. Read the documentation but couldn't figure out the right property or if this is a css class thing.

```
<Text> Hello World, </Text>
<Text> place me next to the Text above! </Text>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Flex for this

```
<Flex>
<Text> Hello World, </Text>
<Text> place me next to the Text above! </Text>
</Flex>
```

Comment: This is not a precise solution, as it will impact the way the text wraps.

Answer (score 34):

[ChakraUI documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/typography/text) on `<Text>` component explains that it renders a `<p>` tag by default.

But, you can swap it to work as a `<span>` tag, by giving `<Text>` the `as` prop. Like this:

```
<Text as="span"> Hello World, </Text>
<Text as="span"> place me next to the Text above! </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the `<Stack>` tag useful.  You can stack items horizontally as well as vertically:

```
<Stack direction='row'>
  <Text>Hello World, </Text>
  <Text>place me next to the Text above!</Text>
</Stack>
```

Alternatively there is a tag called `<HStack>` that does the same thing:

```
<HStack>
  <Text>Hello World, </Text>
  <Text>place me next to the Text above!</Text>
</HStack>
```

This results in:
"Hello World, place me next to the Text above!"